# 404 on Laravel Resource Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting a 404 status code on a laravel resource route when posting a model bound form. The form opening tag is as follows:

```
{!!Form::model($project, ['route' => ['admin.projects.update', $project->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true])!!}
//Form content here
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And the resource route as it appears under routes:list is:

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                               | Name                    | Action                                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | PUT      | admin/projects/{projects}         | admin.projects.update   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminProjectsController@update        |            |
```

and the controller:

```
public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $id)
{
  $data = $request->all();
  $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
  $project->update($data);
  return redirect('admin/projects/edit/all');
}
```

When I check the response in devtools, the payload is attached and the route url is correct. For example, if I am updating a project with an id of 150, the url is

```
http://localhost:8888/project-name/public/admin/projects/150
```

If I don't make any changes, the redirect from the controller works. If I only add files through the form it also works. It's when I change the text input data that I have the issue. I've never had this issue using resourceful routing before and can't for the life of me solve the issue after a couple of hours of trying.

Any fresh eyes see where I am making a mistake?

Comment: What's your update method? Does it redirect to somewhere else if the text value is present?

Comment: The method is PUT (automatically spoofed by Laravel). There are no other redirects. The inputs have their existing values by default.

Comment: Do you have any validation that could redirect to an error page when you have an incorrect input?

Comment: I do, but the redirect is back to the edit page with the $errors array. This doesn't redirect at all. The 404 is on the route url and doesn't redirect unless no changes are made or I add files to the file input (*not shown in the controller example for the purposes of brevity). This is what has me puzzled. If the route is run successfully on a file input then it should run on a text input change too. The fact that it throws a 404 on one and not the other makes no sense. The route is either found or its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Tiredness induced sloppy code. I made the same call twice to a method that brought in the original record data and was used later to reference the record being updated.